# How do you store string inputs in a single array in C++?

Tags: c++

Very simple question but unfortunately I am at a loss. I am trying to build a program where a user is asked to enter nicknames for a pet. Each time they enter a nickname I would like to store that nickname into an array. After they enter a nickname I would also like to list all of the nicknames that they previously entered as well. I would provide some source code but I am not sure where to begin. Any tips or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware of `std::string` and `std::vector`? If not read up on that and then explain what keeps you from using those. If you are explain what keeps you from using them.

Comment: what exactly blocks you ? your request is too vague

Comment: @Yunnosch Hello and thank you for your reply. I was unaware of std::vector. I did some research as you suggested and I was able to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @bruno I apologize for the Vague question. What blocked me was my lack of knowledge regarding the push_back function when adding input values to a vector. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `C++ 11`, a sample code with comments is provided.

```cpp
// header file for standard i/o stream
#include<iostream>

// header file for string
#include<cstring>

// header file for vector container usage
#include<vector>

// use standard namespace, std
using namespace std;

// main start from here
int main() {
    // use vector which is a c++ stl container
    vector<string> names;

    // a temp var
    string name;

    // input until EOF
    while (getline(cin, name)) {
        // push back to the vector container
        names.push_back(name);

        // output what are inside the vector
        // Here I use C++ 11 auto feature
        for (auto pet_name : names) {
            cout << pet_name << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Morrese Updated with comments section.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it. Thank you for including the comments as well. Extremely helpful man, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use std::vector.

Internally std::vector use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements.

So you can simply use std::vector::push_back(petNickName) to store nickname of pet represented as string and not worrying about size of array and other things... .

Comment: Appreciate the reply man and yes I was able to use the push_back function after I initialized an empty vector. Worked like a charm. Thanks again for the reply man. Really appreciate it. Using a vector is much easier than trying to use an array.